# Data binding of ArrayList to JTable in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, binding, jtable

I got data to display on JTable and in following FORMAT, they DO NOT read from any Database, just from an application.

```
Object data = new Object [][] {
    {null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null},
    {null, null, null, null}
};
```

However, How these these could display on JTable through data binding in Netbeans, I cannot find properly binding variables from NetBeans.

However, I create an abstract data model.

```
public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
Object rowData[][] = new Object[ 4 ][ 4 ];


@Override
public int getRowCount () {
    return 4;
}


@Override
public int getColumnCount () {
    return 4;
}


@Override
public void setValueAt ( Object value, int row, int col ) {
    rowData[ row ][ col ] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated( row, col );
}


@Override
public Object getValueAt ( int row, int col ) {
    return rowData[ row ][ col ];
}
}
```

After that, I bind this abstract model to columnModel (a binding variable), and it throws an exception

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   Cannot cast java.lang.String to javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel    at
>   java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3084)     at
>   org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.convertForward(Binding.java:1312)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.getSourceValueForTarget(Binding.java:844)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refreshUnmanaged(Binding.java:1222)
>     at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.refresh(Binding.java:1207)     at
>   org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.tryRefreshThenSave(AutoBinding.java:162)
>     at
>   org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.bindImpl(AutoBinding.java:199)
>     at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.bindUnmanaged(Binding.java:959)
>     at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.bind(Binding.java:944)     at
>   org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup.bind(BindingGroup.java:143)

I am new in data binding with JTable, does any option I could do for such kind of problem?

[image: Data binding properties for JTable in NetBeans]

Comment: I think that there are two very simialir question in this week

Comment: Can you post the link to me? thanks!